# Can futures buying/selling distort price discovery?

Tags: financial-markets

How credible is the suggestion that specific parties distort price discovery (*rig* the market) of a given asset by buying/selling corresponding futures contracts or any other derivatives.

Should these position not unwind at some point causing a reversal effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can futures buying/selling distort price discovery?

Yes, that is plausible although will not necessarily be the case. I will focus on put & call options.

Consider the [put-call parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Put%E2%80%93call_parity), which I rewrite as

$$S+P=C+K*exp(-rt)$$

where *S* denotes the stock [price], *P* put, *C* call, and *K* the strike price.

Buying enough call options will increase *C*. If that were the only change in the market (regarding this stock), that would "break" the put-call parity and therefore an arbitrage opportunity would ensue.

Since K is fixed, the only possible changes to offset *C*'s increase are an increase of *P* and/or of *S*. An agent who notices *C* going up is likely to interpret that someone else has information in the sense that *S* will go up.

Unless that agent also has information in the opposite direction, it would be irrational for him to buy *P* in his attempt to take advantage of the arbitrage opportunity. Thus, he is likelier to buy *S* instead of *P* at least while the put-call parity is restored. Buying *S* tends increase its price (as is the case with *any* financial instrument).

Similarly, in the event of *C*'s increase, the agent might set up a strategy that consists of taking a short position on *C* and hedge it by taking a long position on *S* (he might have to borrow because *C*<*S*, but that is irrelevant to the point). Opening that long position tends to increase *S*.

Comment: Can you comment on short vs long term effect? Especially with regard to my last sentence?

Comment: @FrankRem Reversal/unwinding effects are hard to foretell, more so in the long term. But if buying *C* causes enough increase in *S*, then exercising in-the-money Calls at expiry cannot push *S* down: to the extent that the seller of these options shall honor its obligation, the demand of *S* is non-decreasing. If buying *P* brings *S* down, the effect (on *S*) of exercising ITM Puts at expiry may depend on whether the options buyer owns stock to deliver them when exercising his Puts. Subsequent reversals and/or contagions depend on the new stockowner's pace & timing for transacting *S*.